# I cannot get VisualPHPUnit to run my tests

Tags: phpunit

I installed [VisualPHPUnit](http://mattmueller.me/blog/phpunit-test-report-unit-testing-in-the-browser) as described here.  I'm using XAMPP.

define('PEAR_PATH', 'c:\xampp\php\pear');
  define('TEST_DIRECTORY', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\visualphpunit\tests');

When I run, I see no text, only nicely formatted blanks.  Haven't been find-by-google anyone else who has reported an empty rendering of the VisualPHPUnit screen.

Left side shows "

```
VisualPHPUnit
Tests-------------
Options ------------
Archives -----------
Graphs -------------
```

And the right side is a big blank.

Running phpunit from command-line works fine.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>phpunit visualphpunit\tests
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

..foo { breaks: this } barI.some stuffFsome stuffES

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.25Mb

There was 1 error:



C:\xampp\htdocs\visualphpunit\tests\PUTest.php:8
C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Incomplete: 1, Skipped: 1.

C:\xampp\htdocs>
```

Answer (score 1):

NSinopoli (developer of VisualPHPUnit) here.

It's strongly recommended to report any bugs/issues with VPU on the [project's issue tracker](https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit/issues).

That said, @edorian's diagnosis is incorrect - having output in your tests does **not** break VPU.  (It's actually collected and rendered below the results of the test that contains it.)

"When I run, I see no text, only nicely formatted blanks" - did you select any tests in the file selector before clicking "Run Tests"?  Running VPU without selecting any tests will get you the blanks you've described.  If that's not the case, are you running the tests with any "Options" selected?  If so, there could be a configuration issue which is preventing proper rendering of the results.

Comment: Do you therefore support VisualPHPUnit? There is no more issue tracker on Github...

Answer (score 0):

You have output in your tests. As far as i remember this breaks VisualPHPUnit because it damages the json log file used by VisualPHPUnit.

Remove the output from your tests and it should work